# MongoDB count all likes and posts for a single user using the aggregation pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I need an endpoint that returns the user's info, amount of post's they've submitted and the sum of all likes their post's have received.

I'm using `MongoDB` for my database along with `Mongoose` for my `Node` server.

These are my models:

```
    var userSchema = new Schema({
        'username' : String,
        'email' : String,
        'password' : String
    });

    var photoSchema = new Schema({
        'text' : String,
        'path' : String,
        'timestamp': Number,
        'postedBy' : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user"}
    });

    var likeSchema = new Schema({
        'timestamp' : Number,
        'photo' : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'photo'},
        'user' : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'}
    });
```

I've already accomplished this by using Javascript and multiple queries:

```
// Get user
let user = await userModel.findOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)})
                        .select("_id, username")
                        .lean()
                        .exec();

// Get all users photos
let photos = await photoModel.find({postedBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id)})
                        .select("_id")
                        .exec();

// Sum likes for all photos
let likes = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++)
    likes += (await likeModel.find({photo: photos[i]._id}).exec()).length;
```

But I want to try it with the aggregate pipeline. This is my failed attempt:

```
let user = await userModel.aggregate(
        [
                {
                        $match: {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}
                }, 
                {
                        $unset: ["email", "password", "__v"]
                },
                {
                        $lookup: {
                                from: "photos",
                                localField: "_id",
                                foreignField: "postedBy",
                                as: "photos"
                        }
                }, 
                {
                        $lookup: { 
                                from: "likes",
                                localField: "photos._id",
                                foreignField: "photo",
                                as: "likes"
                        }
                },
                {
                        $unwind: "$photos"
                },
                {
                        $group: {
                                _id: "$_id",
                                username: {$first: "$username"},
                                postCount: {$sum: 1},
                                likeCount: {$sum: 1}
                        }
                }
        ]);
```

I don't know how to get the number of likes for each photo post. Is it possible in a single aggregation pipeline?

Would it make more sense to build it with multiple aggegation pipelines or even just with multiple queries?

Comment: Your query works fine no!!... can you explain what is the problem you face https://mongoplayground.net/p/rOw5podguIP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `$size` to get the size of each array, you won't need the `unwind` or `group` stages.

```
[
    {$match: {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}}, 
    {$lookup: {
               from: "photos",
               localField: "_id",
               foreignField: "postedBy",
               as: "photos"
    }}, 
    {$lookup: { 
                from: "likes",
                localField: "photos._id",
                foreignField: "photo",
                as: "likes"
    }},
    {$project: {
        likeCount: {$size:"$likes"},
        postCount: {$size:"$photos"}
    }}
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yVG9V-R138v)

Alternately, since the only field you are getting from the user collection is `_id`, which you already have, you can skip the match and lookup, and just aggregate the photos collection directly:

```
photoModel.aggregate([
    {$match: {postedBy: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}}, 
    {$lookup: { 
                from: "likes",
                localField: "_id",
                foreignField: "photo",
                as: "likes"
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: "$postedBy",
        likeCount: {$sum:{$size:"$likes"}},
        postCount: {$sum:1}
    }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zZSkFQa3i54)